# Saving multiple values to single user - Firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the below JSON structure that need to be constructed using Firebase.
How can i save the data of the below JSON structure in Firebase.

```
"followers": {
    "user1": {
      "user2": true,
      "user3": true
    }
  }
```

Below is my code but it always replaces the `user2` with `user3`.

```
Map<String, String> data= new HashMap<String, String>();
data.put(uid,"true");
followersTable.child(user1.uid).setValue(data);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `setValue` method is destructive. Meaning it will replace the existing data with the new data given as the parameter.

[Use `updateChildren` instead.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html)

```
Map<String, String> data= new HashMap<String, String>();
data.put(uid,"true");
followersTable.child(user1.uid).updateChildren(data);
```

Comment: Alternately, `followersTable.child("user1").child("user3").setValue(true);` will append an additional child without replacing the contents of `followers/user1`.